# Delay is not working for obserber passing delay time?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I have custom function:

```
activate(seconds: number) {
   of(true)
      .pipe(delay(seconds))
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          console.log("Run...");

        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
}
```

And I call this like:

```
activate(4);
```

Why I get `console.log("Run...");` instantly, wihtout delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delay` takes milliseconds as parameter you should do

```
delay(4000)
```

Comment: that's because your delay is only 4 milliseconds and feels instantly, if you change to lets say 4000 it'll appear after 4 seconds

Comment: I just wanna to recommend this really nice package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms.